# Python - multiple logs/structures in the same xml file using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I wrote an xml file with ElementTree. The problem i'm facing is that I want to write multiple logs in the same xml file.

The code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

#XML

root = ET.Element('LOG')

DATE = ET.SubElement(root, 'DATE')
DATE.text = "child_1"

TIME = ET.SubElement(root, 'TIME')
TIME.text = "child_2"

CC = ET.SubElement(root, 'CC')
CC.text = "child_3"

AMOUNT = ET.SubElement(root, 'AMOUNT')
AMOUNT.text = "child_4"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

#Generating XML
tree.write("file_name.xlm")

#Print
print(open("file_name.xlm").read())
```

Current output example:

```
<LOG><DATE>child_1</DATE><TIME>child_2</TIME><CC>child_3</CC><AMOUNT>child_4</AMOUNT></LOG>
```

Output that I want:

```
<LOG><DATE>child_1</DATE><TIME>child_2</TIME><CC>child_3</CC><AMOUNT>child_4</AMOUNT></LOG><LOG><DATE>child_1</DATE><TIME>child_2</TIME><CC>child_3</CC><AMOUNT>child_4</AMOUNT></LOG><LOG><DATE>child_1</DATE><TIME>child_2</TIME><CC>child_3</CC><AMOUNT>child_4</AMOUNT></LOG>...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just not how xml works. xml documents have one root node, and just one. The closest you can get is by wrapping your <LOG> entries in a container:

```
<ALL_LOGS>
  <LOG>....</LOG>
  <LOG>....</LOG>
</ALL_LOGS>
```

Comment: Okay then let's say I want to leave <LOG> as root and make multiple structures from children only. How would you do it then?

Comment: Just build children elements like you did with LOG and add them to root with `ET.SubElement(root, 'child')`